# Finding unique ids in lines of dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, group-by, grouping

Input - dataframe with more than 50k rows.

Result expected: find unique id's by multiple columns.

F.e. there is dataframe:

```
id par1 par2 par3
1  a    1    AA
2  b    2    AB
3  c    3    AC
4  a    4    AD
5  d    3    AE
6  e    5    AD
7  d    1    AF
```

So the logic is, if any row share common parameter - that is the same unique id, the result should be something like this, made by iterations:
First by par1:

```
id par1 par2 par3  uniq_id
1  a    1    AA    1
2  b    2    AB    2
3  c    3    AC    3
4  a    4    AD    1
5  d    3    AE    4   
6  e    5    AD    5 
7  d    1    AF    4
```

Then by par2:

```
id par1 par2 par3  uniq_id
1  a    1    AA    1
2  b    2    AB    2
3  c    3    AC    3
4  a    4    AD    1
5  d    3    AE    3   
6  e    5    AD    5 
7  d    1    AF    1
```

Then by par3:

```
id par1 par2 par3  uniq_id
1  a    1    AA    1
2  b    2    AB    2
3  c    3    AC    3
4  a    4    AD    1
5  d    3    AE    3   
6  e    5    AD    1 
7  d    1    AF    1
```

Then it should be checked if there are still any misleads:
f.e.  `id=5` and `id=3` should get `uniq_id = 1`, because —id=7`is`uniq_id=1`and`id=7`share`par1`with`id=5`, and because of that`id=3` also changes.

I hope it is clear what I try to explain.
At the moment only working solution made by me - creating `multiple for` cycles and comparing values manually, but since there are lots of observations, it can take forever to execute.

Comment: For `par3` is different logic like for `par1` and `par2` ?

Comment: it has to be the same logic.

Comment: OK, so my solution working for `par3` like you need?

Comment: it factorizes correctly. but the question is how to create one more unique column, by combining every unique value from each previous column.

Comment: My answer was edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`factorize`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.factorize.html) first and then [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) with [`DataFrame.drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html):

```
df['uniq_id'] = pd.factorize(df['par1'])[0] + 1
df['uniq_id'] = df['par2'].map(df.drop_duplicates('par2').set_index('par2')['uniq_id'])
df['uniq_id'] = df['par3'].map(df.drop_duplicates('par3').set_index('par3')['uniq_id'])
print (df)
   id par1  par2 par3  uniq_id
0   1    a     1   AA        1
1   2    b     2   AB        2
2   3    c     3   AC        3
3   4    a     4   AD        1
4   5    d     3   AE        3
5   6    e     5   AD        1
6   7    d     1   AF        1
```

If possible more columns is possible create loop:

```
df['uniq_id'] = pd.factorize(df['par1'])[0] + 1

for col in ['par2','par3']:
    df['uniq_id'] = df[col].map(df.drop_duplicates(col).set_index(col)['uniq_id'])
```